# How android displays UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am studying how Android OS shows app UI on screen.

till now, I can find some UI related classes in Android: SurfaceView, Display, Window, ViewGroup, View and Activity.

But, it is hard for me to understand operational flow of launching a new app and rendering its UI on screen.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I guess even the guy who worked on android for the last few years won't know this stuff.. Honestly I don't know... but one thing for sure it's broad to answer...

Comment: It sure is a broad question, I would recommend you to look at the lifecycle of components starting with [Activity/Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) which hosts UI components, and then take a look at how any [custom view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) is rendered.

There are very good articles on medium and on other channels which will help you understand more on this topic